# Can I create a new Developer Sandbox for free?

Tags: sandbox, developer, enterprise

I am working on an Enterprise Edition of Salesforce Org. I have 3 Developer Sandboxes. Can I create another new Sandbox again? Also does Salesforce charge anything for this new Developer Sandbox?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find info about how many and which sandboxes developer could have per license type here: [Sandbox Licenses and Storage by Type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_environments.htm&type=5)

I am going to quote this as an image:

[image]

Answer is **yes, you can create up to 25 Developer Sandboxes in Enterprice Edition** production for free.

Comment: Thank You very much